# Where is record getting defined in the _master template default theme?

Tags: bolt-cms

I was just going through the contents of the _master.twig and came across the followng lines of code:

```
<title>
            {%- if record.title is defined %}{{ record.title|striptags }} | {% endif -%}
                {{ app.config.get('general/sitename') -}}
            {% if record.title is not defined and app.config.get('general/payoff') %} | {{ app.config.get('general/payoff') }}{% endif -%}
        </title>
```

Now i don't see before this line any other template included , so where exactly is `record` coming from ? Where is it getting defined in the _master template in in bolt ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`record` is one of the variables that get passed in from the controller. It holds the data for the current record you are looking at.

It is available in the `_master.twig` because your record template extends the `_master.twig` template.

Comment: Also, feel free to join our slack channel (https://slack.bolt.cm/). There we can help you much faster :)

Comment: `record is one of the variables that get passed in from the controller`  ....which controller ??

Comment: The frontend controller that receives the request, collects all data and renders the template.

Comment: Thanks and yes i have joined that forum you've suggested :D